# PHP query inserts 2 rows into the table

Tags: php, mysql

OK, here is the deal. I have 3 queries putting data in different tables. 2 of them are in included files. I've tried to put them into the main code, the result was the same. The first two queries inserts one row with the data and a blank row. The third works fine. Here is the code.

This in the main page:

```
<? $p=0;
    if ($select2)
    {
        $event=$select2;
    }
    else
    {
        require_once("insert_gal_name.php5");
    }

    if ($select)
    {
        $folder=$select;
    }
    else
    {
        require_once("insert_folder.php5");
        if (file_exists("Connections/".$folder))
        {
        }
        else
        {
             mkdir("Connections/$folder",0777);
        }
    }

    while($p<$number)
    {
        $p++;

        $dir = 'Connections/'.$folder.'/'; // Директорията в която ще се записват файловете
        copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$p],"$dir".$_FILES['file']['name'][$p]); //Копиране на файла
        echo "Файлът бе качен успешно!<br>"; // Извеждане на съобщение показващо, че файла е качен
        if($_FILES['file']['name'][$p])
        {
            $real_file_name = $dif_of_files.$_FILES['file']['name'][$p];
            $nom_file = str_replace(" ", "", $real_file_name); }

            $query = "INSERT INTO gallery (name, title, day, month, year) VALUES ('$nom_file', '$event', '$day', '$month', '$year')";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }
        if (!$result)
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "All data was uploaded successfuly.";
        }
?>
```

And here are the includes in the order they are placed in the source

```
<?  $query = "INSERT INTO gallery_names (name) VALUES ('$event')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$result)
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The gallery was created successfuly.";
    }
?>

<? $query = "INSERT INTO folders (name) VALUES ('$folder')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$result)
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The folder was created successfuly.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Exactly which query is being added more than once?

Comment: Instead of doing if($select), use something like if(isset($select)) or if($select === true). Its much more precise and easier to read/debug.

Comment: Citizen the last two shown in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
    if($event!='')
    {
        $query1 = "INSERT INTO gallery_names (name) VALUES ('$event')";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
        if (!$result1)
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "The gallery was created successfuly.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The first query should be this: `    $query = "INSERT INTO gallery (name, title, day, month, year) VALUES ('".$nom_file."', '".$event."', '".$day."', '".$month."', '".$year."')";`

Comment: I don't know if this is the  issue because my data is inserted properly exept the blank row. I've puted  if(isset($select)) and now it does not include my pages and yet there now only the blank row is inserted

Comment: then use echo $nom_file; exit;  and check that

Comment: in  gallery_names and folders in this queries is the problem. Everything else works fine.

Comment: then echo $event ;exit; before the query and check that $event is not null

Comment: I echo the $event and I see it's value

Comment: it not inserted the blank record

Comment: I've deleted the second $ in the if statement and it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

If $select2 is false then this code will do two inserts. If $event is empty one of these will be an empty row which sounds like the problem you're having.
What are the values of $select2 and $event? Have you tried debugging them?

Comment: $select2 are the existing galleries genereted in a list menu form the mysql table. The idea it to select an existing gllarey or to write down a new one and this is the $evenet var

Comment: Is $event only set when $select2 has a value? If so this is what will cause the empty row since insert_gal_name.php5 will have nothing to insert.

Comment: No. $event is a field in the form. If there is $select which is a previous event $event assume the value of the $select else the value in the field is inserted

Comment: The idea is if there is a gallery chosen the insert_gal_name.php5 not to be executed